# using material-ui with SCSS directly in React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I have an issue about using styles in React component. I want to use SCSS instead of either using the `withStyle` function or importing pure CSS file into a JS file.

For example I want to import my SCSS file into `ButtonComponent.js` as below:

1. `import './buttonStyle.scss'`
2. Put my theme configuration in a SCSS file named `theme.scss`
3. Import `theme.scss` into my SCSS files
4. Make use of the SCSS classes in `className` of the components.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a bundler with a loader that can compile scss into css.

You could use **webpack** with [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader).  A minimal configuration would look something like this:

```
// webpack.config.js

var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './foo.js',

    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'foo.bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

You can read more about getting started with webpack [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).